# issues with File exists command windows phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

i was found this code on internet to check file exists

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (store.FileExists("Setting.xml"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("have file");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("haven't file");                    
                }
            }
```

When i try, it only show condition "haven't file". whether have or not Setting.xml file? (i can load this file by XDocument data = XDocument.Load("Setting.xml");  to do or not) ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this "Setting.xml" file is in IsolatedStorage?

Because, in order to access the files from IsolatedStorage - you should use the IsolatedStorageFileStream.